# How to toggle between code-behind and markup in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I previously had VS2013 Premium installed and had the view.toggle command mapped to F7 so I could easily toggle between code-behind and markup (and vice versa). Now that I have upgraded to VS2013 Ultimate, the view.toggle command doesn't even exists. Can I get this command back somehow, or implement similar behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the command is now called View.ToggleDesigner.

The name is misleading because it does not toggle to the Designer, it does in-fact toggle between markup and code-behind.

[image]

Comment: It actually toggles to the Designer in my case, to my dismay.